# Calling and showing photo from layer shown in composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, geotag, photos

What I'm trying to do is to see images from photo-layer that are shown in the composer.

[image: Layout]

There will be 6 images in each map. There will be a datatable from the point layer that contains the path and the name of the photo file.

What I want is that the first photo-square calls the first row from the table and shows the photo from the path. The same process for each of the squares.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  I removed your second one to prevent your question being too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution even if it is not as automatic as I want. Use the next expression into the square of the image:

```
attribute( get_feature( 'Fotos','join_cod',  @item_id ),'Path')
```

The key is that now we have just to change the name of the element (ID of the element) what can be done quickly in the upper right box of elements.

So in this case, if I write 33 in the name of the element, the expression will look into the table of 'Fotos' and pick the 'path' of the photo with 'join_cod' = 33.

It works fine. When photos are not automatically updated you just need to deactivate and activate the expression.

[image: screenshot of the case]