# how do I create a report with photos imported to my map?

Tags: photos, reports, geotag, thumbnail

How to create a report with geotagged photos printed after the map?

I imported the photos using the processing toolbox and then used an HTML code in the map tips so they pop up when the cursor scrolls over the image.

I want to generate a report with the map and then the thumbnails of the photos without having to add each image just automatically generate the thumbnails with a couple per page.

How to achieve it?

Comment: which software are you using?

Comment: Mac version 3.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that. Here you could get some ideas:
[Calling and showing photos from layer shown in composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251595/calling-and-showing-photo-from-layer-shown-in-composer)

Hope it helps and don't hesitate to ask again.

Comment: thanks! that looks like what I was thinking I'll give it a try and let you know if I run into any issues trying to duplicate your process